# VLCJ pro - Implementation of NativeLog

Tags: java, vlcj

I am trying to build an application that can open an IP camera stream, and if there are failures in that stream, the application should be notified of the nature of the failure, depending on which it takes necessary action. I got this to work pretty well with VLCJ. But since I may encounter situations wherein I detect a failure on one of the cameras, but I have an alternate camera that can be used, I would need to have the capability of having multiple instances of a media player in the same application. This is why I am trying out the trial version 1.2 of VLCJ pro.

However, I am not able to access the logging mechanism like in NativeLog in VLCJ. When astream fails, the logs are printed out on closing the JFrame which has the canvas, but how do I check these strings in my application, and use this information to execute alternate actions? I have gone through the user guide of VLCJ pro, but there doesn't seem to be a mention about this. Any ideas would be very helpful and much appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I don't want the logs to be stored in a logfile, rather something like a runtime access to generated log messages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not supported.

It might be possible for this to be added in the future, but there are currently no plans to do so.